# is it possible to run the program that needs NVIDIA GPU?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I am facing a problem related to GPU's.

I am trying to execute a program in my laptop and facing the following issue.

> AssertionError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check
> that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
> http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

When I check the graphics of my system, it is showing that the graphics of my system is `Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)`.

So, I am suspecting that my system does not have any NVIDIA gpu. Is it true?

If true, is it impossible to run the program on my system (by making changes)? Or is there any way to make the program runnable on my system?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what program you are trying to run.

Comment: What is the software you are trying to run?  You should ask about the problem you face instead of asking how to perform a solution you think might work (If you don't actually have a NVIDIA GPU, you are probably way off the mark) See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: @CharlesGreen   I am executing this https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix

Comment: @Nmath it is a deep learning program given above.....

Answer (score 4):

Get the list of graphic hardware :

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

If the hardware has no NVidia GPU, you must run PYTorch with CPU
See : https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/docs/tips.md

Run a model on CPU with `gpu_ids` option set to `-1`:

```
--gpu_ids -1
```